# Constant scan in query plan leading to massive cardinality estimation error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

My query uses GETDATE() and therefore gets some constant scan operators in the 
[image: query plan].

The estimated number of rows on the outer input of the inner join is 2, but the actual number of rows is 262442.

I believe that with such a huge amount of rows, an inner loop join will be very inefficient. The estimation error also leads to a tempdb spill in the sort operator.

Is there something I can do? (Query hints, statistics etc?)

Here is the entire [query plan including SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJxoFO5w4).

Comment: What is the query you're actually running? Using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) would be more useful that a picture as well.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @Larnu, add DDL with indexes to your question too since the end goal is probably to improve query performance. Cardinality estimation is only part of the picture.

Comment: I've added the query plan to my question. I would rather leave indexes out of this for now, the overall performance is OK for my use case, and I'm mainly asking because I want to understand what is happening here. Thanks!

Comment: My two guesses are stale statistics, giving the wrong estimates, or parameter sniffing caching a bad plan

Comment: It seems applying functions to the columns is the culprit: `AND datepart(year,[MTMS_Staging_Dev].[MTMS].[ORDS].[ORDSDATE_ENT] as [ORDS].[ORDSDATE_ENT]) >= datepart(year,getdate())-(2) AND datepart(year,[MTMS_Staging_Dev].[MTMS].[ORDS].[ORDSDATE_ENT] as [ORDS].[ORDSDATE_ENT]) <= datepart(year,getdate())`

Comment: I would expect much better estimations (and perhaps index use) by refactoring as to avoid applying the `DATEPART` functions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it!